# BlueHost - No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg, bluehost

I am currently trying to run my application on BlueHost.

I already clone, setup, and install the application.

When I tried `rails s` the application can running on http://my.domain.com:3000

But it's return

`could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

I am using PG for the database but I am not sure why this happens.

Comment: Well is the database server running and listening on port 5432 and accepting connections?

Comment: @DrColossos - How can I check if the database server is running or not?

Comment: I have no idea what bluehost does/offers/... but on a regular linux box, I would do sudo service postgresql status to see if it is running or not. If it is running, I would check the postgresql.conf file to see if it listens on the desired address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After did some research this is happen because I need to reconfigure PG user and database manually. And it working like charms. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: You should explain what you did so that others with the same problem can fix their problem.